# Extract all nested text between <p> and end of <div> HTML tags using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse through and extract data from HTML using Python and Beautifulsoup.

The sample HTML looks like this (it has multiple such structures being repeated:

[image: Sample Browser Render]

Here is a sample code snippet that generated the above screenshot:

```
<div class="indented"><p id="1" class="">
    <strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>Regional</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>
</p>
    <ul id="2" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about region 1
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="3" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about region 2</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="4" class="">
        <strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>Country</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>
    </p>
    <ul id="5" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 1
            <ul id="ac" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="ad" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="ae" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="6" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 2
            <ul id="ab" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p id="7" class=""><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>City</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></p>
    <ul id="8" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about city 1</li>
        <ul id="acc" class="bulleted-list">
            <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
                <ul id="add" class="bulleted-list">
                    <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="aee" class="bulleted-list">
            <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul id="9" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 2
            <figure id="a" class="image"><a
                    href="a.png"><img
                    style="width:3040px"
                    src="a.png"></a>
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is a sample of how the above appears in Chrome's console:
[image: Sample HTML Structure]

My objective is to get all the nested text under the City <p> tag. You can assume that the City <p> tag will always be the last <p> tag before the <div> it sits in is closed out. Under the City <p> tag, bullet points can have multiple layers of nesting and may have text in different formats (eg: bolded, italicized and so on). Any non-text data like images should be ignored.

Given the HTML structure seen in the Chrome console above, unfortunately the <ul> elements are not direct children of the <p> tag, which is making it difficult for me to accomplish this task.

Anyone have advice on how I can do this programmatically? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "all the nested text under the City <p> tag"? Do you need all text belong the nodes with id=8 and id=9 or something else?

Comment: Issue is solved. See accepted answer. Thanks @SergeyZaykov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `tag.find_previous` to check if the tag you're in is under `City` or not. E.g.:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")  # html_text contains your snippet from the question

text = []
for ul in soup.select("ul:not(:has(ul))"):
    p = ul.find_previous("p")
    if p and p.text.strip() == "City":
        text.append(ul.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))

print("\n".join(text))
```

Prints:

```
Lorem ipsum about city 1
Lorem ipsum about country 2
```

---

EDIT:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div class="indented"><p id="1" class="">
    <strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>Regional</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>
</p>
    <ul id="2" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about region 1
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="3" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about region 2</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="4" class="">
        <strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>Country</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>
    </p>
    <ul id="5" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 1
            <ul id="ac" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="ad" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="ae" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="6" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 2
            <ul id="ab" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p id="7" class=""><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>City</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></p>
    <ul id="8" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about city 1</li>
        <ul id="acc" class="bulleted-list">
            <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
                <ul id="add" class="bulleted-list">
                    <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="aee" class="bulleted-list">
            <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul id="9" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 2
            <figure id="a" class="image"><a
                    href="a.png"><img
                    style="width:3040px"
                    src="a.png"></a>
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")


def fn(ul, level=0):
    for tag in ul.find_all(["li", "ul"], recursive=False):
        if tag.name == "li":
            print(
                "\t" * level,
                " ".join(c.strip() for c in tag.find_all(string=True, recursive=False)),
                sep="",
            )
            for li_ul in tag.find_all("ul", recursive=False):
                fn(li_ul, level + 1)
        else:
            fn(tag, level + 1)


for ul in soup.select("div > ul"):
    fn(ul)
```

Prints:

```
Lorem ipsum about region 1
Lorem ipsum about region 2
Lorem ipsum about country 1   
        Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
        Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2
        Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3
Lorem ipsum about country 2 
        Sub lorem ipsum about country 2
Lorem ipsum about city 1
        Sub lorem ipsum about country 1 
                Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2
        Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3
Lorem ipsum about country 2
```

Comment: Hey Andrej - thank you for this. It works, but only picks out the final child of a nested list. So for example, if I added a child ("Sample child") to "Lorem ipsum about country 2", I would only get the child not the parent. I am trying to get all bullet points under city, regardless of how nested they are. Does that make sense?

Comment: @nb123 Can you please edit your question and put there what do you expect from the HTML snippet (concrete text). Because now it's not clear to me.

Comment: I have edited the question. In your current code, with the new edits, I get this result:
Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2
Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3
Lorem ipsum about country 2
This means that the following have gone missing:
Lorem ipsum about city 1
Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
I need all the bullet points to be extracted, ideally whilst maintaining the parent-child structure. Does that help?

Comment: @nb123 But how do you want to maintain the parent-child structure? What output data-structure do you need?

Comment: A unique separator will do - so for the above example, the ideal output would be:

Lorem ipsum about city 1<>Sub lorem ipsum about country 1<>Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2

Lorem ipsum about city 1<>Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3

Lorem ipsum about Country 2

The <> is a delimiter (can be any delimiter) and each parent to child complete traversal is a line (so that in a text file, each line indicates full hierarchical relationship). Hope it is clear now?

Comment: @nb123 I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is invalid which makes working with standard tools more difficult than it needs to be. See the [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

Your `<p>` elements should include the unordered lists and not end immediately after your opening `<p>`. Nested unordered lists must be done properly (inside a list item, not as a direct child of another unordered list.

In terms of selecting the last `<p>` child of some `<div>` elements, or any elements whatsoever, this is what CSS selectors do. A web developer would simply use JavaScript's `.querySelector` then get the `.textContent`.

Any other tool for this job is the wrong tool.

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

divs.forEach(function(div){
  console.log(div.querySelector('p:last-of-type').nextSibling.nextSibling.textContent)

})
```

```html
<div class="indented"><p id="1" class="">
    <strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>Regional</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>
</p>
    <ul id="2" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about region 1
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="3" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about region 2</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="4" class="">
        <strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>Country</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></strong>
    </p>
    <ul id="5" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 1
            <ul id="ac" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="ad" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="ae" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="6" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 2
            <ul id="ab" class="bulleted-list">
                <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p id="7" class=""><strong><strong><strong><strong><strong>City</strong></strong></strong></strong></strong></p>
    <ul id="8" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about city 1</li>
        <ul id="acc" class="bulleted-list">
            <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1
                <ul id="add" class="bulleted-list">
                    <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="aee" class="bulleted-list">
            <li style="list-style-type:circle">Sub lorem ipsum about country 1-3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
    <ul id="9" class="bulleted-list">
        <li style="list-style-type:disc">Lorem ipsum about country 2
            <figure id="a" class="image"><a
                    href="a.png"><img
                    style="width:3040px"
                    src="a.png"></a>
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```